# Prefix filename with sequential number. Be prompted (powershell)

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying the **insert a number** as a prefix "`n__`"  for each filename in the `CWD` (not recursively). `n` is a number with increments of +1, user needs to enter the first value.  To number, the files **must** be pre-sorted in lowest-value-first order based on the filename.

```
$i = Read-Host 'Enter first file number'
$confirmation = Read-Host "Re-enter first file number"
if ($confirmation -eq '=') {
    # proceed
}
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object | Rename-Item -NewName { "$i+1" + "__" + $_.Name }
```

What I am missing at the i+ and in order to ensure that the files are sorted for numbering?

Intended result:

```
101__121.ext
102__211.ext
103__375.ext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# putting [int] before the variable will insure that your input is an integer and not a string
[int] $i = Read-Host 'Enter first file number' 
[int] $confirmation = Read-Host "Re-enter first file number"

# Your if statement seemed to not make sense. This is my take
if ($confirmation -eq $i)
{
     Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object | Foreach-Object -Process {
         $NewName = '{0}__{1}' -f $i,$_.Name # String formatting e.x. 1__FileName.txt
         $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName # rename item
         $i ++ # increment number before next iteration
     }
}
else
{
    Write-Warning -Message "Your input did not match"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very nice!  A piggyback Q: What would be the change if I want to **presort the files based on LastWriteTime** (oldest first) in order to append the `n__` ? (instead of the characters in the filename sorting)?

Comment: @user3026965 `Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | Foreach-Object -Process {`

Comment: @user3026965 There is also a `CreationTime` property on file objects you could sort on.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming files are numeric names (`121.ext`,`211.ext`,etc.)

```
[Int]$UserInput = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter first file number'
[Int]$Confirmation = Read-Host -Prompt 'Re-enter first file number'
If ($Confirmation -ne $UserInput) { Exit }

$Collection = Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression={[Int]$_.BaseName}}

While (($UserInput - $Confirmation) -lt $Collection.Count)
{
    $Collection[$UserInput - $Confirmation] |
        Rename-Item -NewName "$($UserInput)__$($_.Name)"
    $UserInput++
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I am getting `+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (`... error, likely due to the fact that the files do contain characters other than numbers.

Comment: @user3026965 my word of caution if you require the filenames to be in order: text sorting is not the same as numeric sorting.  i.e., `201`, and `2011` will be next to each other before `301`.  Just remove the `-Property` argument from the sort and my solution will work for you.

Comment: thank you! yes, i see your "Assuming files are numeric names".